# Output SQL table array php - Foreach Loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

I have a database table with information inside. I am having an issue populating a `foreach` loop with the list of entries to the table.
I am attempting to order the array by ascending date in `variable[1]` (event_date).

Eventually, the output will be a `<div class="row-fluid">` for each of the entries and that each one will be in order of date and the ones behind the current date will not show up within the array.

Currently, I am getting an output that I am unsure as to what it really is. I have one entry, and I have 5 rows of events with odd letters in each.

In summary:

1. Foreach loop of each table entry
2. Array ordered by ascending date
3. Dates previous to the current date do not show up in the array

My current code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT event_id, event_date, event_time, name, body, image FROM events");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {

            foreach($row as $variable) { ?>

                <div id="" class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="well span12">
                        <div class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a class="various fancybox.ajax" href="#"><img src="<?php echo $variable[5]; ?>"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- span3 -->
                        <div class="span1 ev-date text-center">
                                <span class="month"><?php echo $month; ?></span>
                                <span class="day"><?php echo $day; ?></span>
                                <span class="year"><?php echo $year; ?></span>
                        </div><!-- span1 -->
                        <div class="span8 ev-head">
                        <a class="various fancybox.ajax" href="#"><h3><?php echo $variable[3]; ?></h3></a>
                        <p><?php echo substr($variable[4], 0, 150); ?> <a class="various fancybox.ajax" href="#"><span class="readmore"> ..Read More</span></a></p>

                        </div><!-- span8 -->
                    </div><!-- well span12 -->
                </div><!-- appeal# -->  

        <?php
            }
        }
?>
```

You may also notice the `<?php echo $month ?>` `$day` and `$year`. Another question I have, although I am researching this as I type, is how can I strip the `event_date` variable into just DAY, MONTH, and YEAR? (I may as well ask whilst I am here) I am not sure if natcasesort is the correct function here.

Thanks!

Comment: "while($row" is setting $row with one row of results. Delete your line with "foreach" and address your columns in this way: $row["event_id"]

Comment: If event_date is a date field you can use substr($row["event_date"],0,4) for $year, substr($row["event_date"],5,2) for $month and substr($row["event_date"],8,2) for $day

Comment: I've just re-read it all with a clear head. Removed the foreach loop and works currently! :) The next step is sorting it all using the event_date variable. Earliest date to latest, but ahead of the current date/time. So no previous events to be shown.

Comment: Then add "ORDER BY event_date DESC" to your SQL statement

Comment: That makes sense and works!! I'm self-teaching sql currently.. :) Thanks